# Google Drive python client / How to filter list of files with 'ownedByMe' and 'properties'?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client, file-listing

I succeed to use the `q` parameter to filter files in Google Drive which names are not a given value, with following code.

```py
    prefix = 'forbidden_name'
    res = files.list(
                     q="name != '" + prefix + "'",
                     pageSize=800, pageToken=None,
                     fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name, parents, properties, ownedByMe)').execute()
```

I use the same service account to create these files and to list them.

I would then like to filter only the ones created by this service account.
To do so, I tried using `ownedByMe` parameter, as listed in [Google Documentation (Google API v3)](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files).

But I get following error.

```py
    res = files.list(
                     q="ownedByMe = true",
                     pageSize=800, pageToken=None,
                     fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name, parents, properties, ownedByMe)').execute()
```

```sh
HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=ownedByMe+%3D+true&pageSize=800&fields=nextPageToken%2C+files%28id%2C+name%2C+parents%2C+properties%2C+ownedByMe%29&alt=json returned "Invalid Value">
```

Also, when trying to filter on `properties`, for instance with a key `data_type`, I get the following error.

```py
    res = files.list(
                     q="properties['data_type'] = 'whatever'",
                     pageSize=800, pageToken=None,
                     fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name, parents, properties, ownedByMe)').execute()
```

```sh
HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=properties%5B%27data_type%27%5D+%3D+%27whatever%27&pageSize=800&fields=nextPageToken%2C+files%28id%2C+name%2C+parents%2C+properties%2C+ownedByMe%29&alt=json returned "Invalid Value">
```

Please, any idea what is wrong in my code?
Thanks a lot for your help!
Bests,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, in the current stage, there are no query of `ownedByMe = true` and `properties['data_type'] = 'whatever'`. I think that this is the reason of your issue of `Invalid Value`. So how about the following modification?

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, `ownedByMe = true` is achieved. In this case, please use the following search query.

#### Modified search query:

```
'###' in owners
```

- In your case, `###` is the email of service account.

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, `properties['data_type'] = 'whatever'` is achieved. In this case, please use the following search query.

#### Modified search query:

```
properties has {key='data_type' and value='whatever'}
```

### References:

- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
- [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/query-ref)
- [Search for files and folders](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files)